# AH01215: (8) Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/python/hello.py' failed: /var/www/python/hello.py

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, cgi

I am trying to run python as CGI in apache server. Python version is 2.7.12.
Here is my apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   <Directory /var/www/python>
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/python
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My python script /var/www/python/hello.py looks like this

```
print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n')
print("Hello, World!")
```

When I access the url I get the Internal Server Error, I got the details from error.log file and it says ,

> [Sun Dec 11 09:53:40.694909 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6812] [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/python/hello.py' failed: /var/www/python/hello.py
>   [Sun Dec 11 09:53:40.695312 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6812] [client 127.0.0.1:36282] End of script output before headers: hello.py

PHP scripts are still working fine on the server.
How to fix this issue with py files ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your script needs a "shebang" line, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line. Also, make sure the script is executable with `chmod`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n')
print("ąęśłłłóąś UTF answer")
```

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my day :). I am still a bit confused on why your answer works, but the answer above that @charlie martin gives does not work :/

Comment: Because of : # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-