# How to solve internal server error 500 for python(Xampp)

Tags: python, macos, apache, xampp, python-3.8

I am getting this error:

```
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: python.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
192.168.64.2
Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d PHP/7.4.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I have done the following:

Added .py to Addhandler in httpd.conf

[image]

I have done the following:

Added .py to Addhandler in httpd.conf

image

I have also installed pip and pymysql

I am using python 3.8.3

I have also have the permissions set to chmod 755

In the error logs it says:

```
[Sun Jun 07 01:36:53.823419 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 847] [client 192.168.64.1:51293] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py' failed: /opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py
[Sun Jun 07 01:36:53.824918 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 847] [client 192.168.64.1:51293] End of script output before headers: python.py
```

Heres my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
print ('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print ('\r\n')
print ()
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('Hello Python')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

I am using mac

Comment: check python.py file permission.

Comment: It's chmod 755 already

Comment: tested script with `#!/usr/bin/env python` line and working fine at my end.permission of file was 777.

Comment: chage permission to a+x `/opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py` and test.

Comment: still same error as my last comment, might this be the problem that when I do cd in my terminal I just drag the folder or does not affect anything?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082302/ah01215-8-exec-format-error-exec-of-var-www-python-hello-py-failed-var

Comment: wait no it is this error with this shebang line(the correct shebang line for python 3.8.3) `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8` it is this error `[Mon Jun 08 00:56:18.067657 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 835] [client 192.168.64.1:50286] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py' failed: /opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/python.py
[Mon Jun 08 00:56:18.068687 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 835] [client 192.168.64.1:50286] End of script output before headers: python.py
`

Comment: Share ll output of python.py script

Comment: internal server error 500

Comment: share ` ll /opt/lampp/htdocs/11-python/` command output.

Comment: on Idle? Hello Python

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: No, it is still showing me the internal server error

Comment: Ca you tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: I was facing the same issue.The issue got resolved after changing file permission to 777.

Comment: if it were a permission problem it would say `(13) permission denied` in the error logs

Comment: for exec permission it will say `2)No such file or directory: exec of`

Comment: yes that's what it says, so how can I solve that

Comment: @pandurang please answer

Comment: @Pandurang please answer I need your answer urgently now I have been stuck on this for 3 months, I've also tried using other python files and setting their permissions to 777 but I keep getting that error message

Comment: My issue is resolved after changing permission to `a+x`. I don't have any answers.